# How to create pipe between Write-Host and Read-Host?

Tags: powershell-3.0

Using PowerShell I want to read the output written by `Write-Host` with the `Read-Host`, by creating a pipe. How could I do this?

Comment: `Write-Host` writes to the host console, so its output doesn't go into the pipeline. `Read-Host` is for prompting the user for input, so it doesn't read from the pipeline. Why do you think you need this? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: As stated above, Read-Host cannot accept a pipe, you can read more here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849945.aspx

Comment: can we know what you are trying to achieve by this?